# Из строки в математическое выражение с возможностью расчета %, java

Tags: java, android, строки, парсер

Здравствуйте!
Очень нужна ваша помощь. Я новичок в программировании, поэтому заранее сорри если задаю глупый вопрос:)
Делаю калькулятор для android. Он должен иметь возможность расчета выражения, например: (84-12) + (18+5)%
Сторонние библиотеки (типа arity) использовать запрещено. 
У меня проблема с написанием кода для расчета процентов. Это должен быть именно процент, а не остаток от деления. 
Прошу подсказать ссылки, где я могу посмотреть похожий алгоритм (парсер из строки в мат.выражение с возможностью расчета процентов) либо образец кода.
Заранее спасибо

```
equal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        String orgString = textView.getText().toString();
        result.setText(findValue (orgString));
        textView.setText(null);
        clearResult = false;
        doubleMathActionBug = false;
        doubleDotBug = true;
    }

    public String findValue (String finalStr) {

        while (finalStr.contains("(") && finalStr.contains(")")) {
            int fIndex = finalStr.indexOf("(");
            int nIndex = finalStr.indexOf(")");
            String subString = finalStr.substring(fIndex + 1, nIndex);
            finalStr = finalStr.substring(0, fIndex)
                    + calculate(subString)
                    + finalStr.substring(nIndex + 1,
                    finalStr.length());
        }
        return calculate(finalStr);

    }

    public String calculate(String finalString) {

        while (finalString.contains("(") && finalString.contains(")")) {
            findValueInBraces(finalString);
        }
        while (!isNum(finalString)) {
            List<Integer> positions = getOperandPosition(finalString);
            int pos = positions.get(0);
            if (positions.size() >= 2 && positions.get(1) != null) {
                int nxtPos = positions.get(1);
                finalString = getValue(finalString.substring(0, nxtPos), pos)
                        + finalString.substring(nxtPos, finalString.length());
            } else {
                finalString = getValue(
                        finalString.substring(0, finalString.length()), pos);
            }
        }
        return finalString;

    }

    public boolean isNum(String str) {
        if (str.contains("+") || str.contains("-") || str.contains("*")
                || str.contains("/") || str.contains("%")) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public List<Integer> getOperandPosition(String str) {

        List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        if (str.contains("+")) {
            integers.add(str.indexOf("+"));
        }

        if (str.contains("-")) {
            integers.add(str.indexOf("-"));
        }

        if (str.contains("*")) {
            integers.add(str.indexOf("*"));
        }

        if (str.contains("/")) {
            integers.add(str.indexOf("/"));
        }
        if (str.contains("%")) {
            integers.add(str.indexOf("%"));
        }

        Collections.sort(integers);
        return integers;
    }

    public String getValue(String str, int pos) {
        double finalVal = 0;
        double a = Double.parseDouble(str.substring(0, pos));
        double b = Double.parseDouble(str.substring(pos + 1, str.length()));
        char c = str.charAt(pos);

        if (c == '*') {
            finalVal = a * b;
        } else if (c == '/') {
            finalVal = a / b;
        } else if (c == '+') {
            finalVal = a + b;
        } else if (c == '-') {
            finalVal = a - b;

        }else if (c == '%') {
            c = str.charAt(0, pos);
            if (c == '*') {
                finalVal = a/100*b;
            } else if (c == '+') {
                finalVal = a + a/100*b;
            } else if (c == '-') {
                finalVal = a - a/100*b;

            }

            }
        return String.valueOf(finalVal);
    }
});
```

Comment: В чём конкретно содтоит проблема при расчета процентов. Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш код, даже если он не работает.

Comment: спасибо за отклик, добавила код в вопрос. Полагаю проблема в самом конце (где %). Я не совсем понимаю как написать логику для с==%

Comment: `c = str.charAt(0, pos);` внутри `if (c == '%')` Кажется должно быть `c = str.charAt(pos-1);` или как-то так. Вам же там нужен предыдущий оператор, а не тот же самый.

Comment: Вообще я бы посоветовал копать в сторону обратной польской записи, она позволяет разобраться с проблемами последовательности операций, скобочками и всяким таким.

Comment: А встроенные в java можно либы использовать? К примеру ScriptManager http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/

Comment: @lllyct  встроенные скрипты тоже нельзя использовать :(( Нужно написать логику. Я пробовала JavaScript использовать, но там % рассчитывается как остаток от деления, поэтому этот вариант у меня не пропустили. 
Да, я тоже думаю проблема с позицией с=str.charAt(...), сейчас попробую pos-1.
"копать в сторону обратной польской записи" - это что, простите?

Comment: [Обратная польская запись](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C) - форма записи математических выражений. Суть в том, что для такой записи алгоритм обработки выражения будет не очень сложным и его вполне можно найти. И алгоритм преобразования обычного выражения в такую запись тоже можно найти. И вам не придется изобретать велосипед. Ваш код, например, будет некорректно работать если добавить в выражение вложенные скобочки.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую поискать алгоритм

Comment: да возьмите уже высчитанное выражение, округлите его до > .5 | < .5,  проставьте условие, далее выводите уже результат в окно

Comment: GenCloud не поняла что вы имели ввиду... Как это будет выглядеть в коде? 
По обратной польской записи - если не трудно, можете кинуть ссылку на алгоритм кода, где есть расчет процентов? Опять же, все операторы есть, а именно логику для процентов не могу найти

Comment: Обратная польская запись - это так, к слову. У вас после того как разберетесь с процентами будут проблемы с последовательностью выполнения математических операций. Это отдельная тема.

Comment: По вашей конкретной проблеме с процентами: `c = str.charAt(pos-1);` помогло?

Comment: И еще попробуйте для начала более простые выражения без скобок. Например 96 + 23%. Суть в том, чтобы решать одну проблему за раз: проверить сложение с процентами, если работает переходить к остальному по порядку. В последнюю очередь скобки, ибо с ними много проблем.

Comment: Собственно полноценный калькулятор есть [тут](https://gist.github.com/SunDrop/8945795), нужно только поменять логику для процентов.

Comment: Кстати, за обратную польскую нотацию спасибо. Нашла алгоритм (хоть и без вычисления процентов), но выражения с любой последовательностью и скобками считает верно. c = str.charAt(pos-1); - неа, не помогло

Comment: ага, в этом калькуляторе % тоже остаток от деления (на который дали ссылку) попробую поменять, если что-то получится, напишу.  lllyct, спасибо за подсказки))

Comment: Все, написала код для процента в обратной польской. Алгоритм взяла здесь http://javatalks.ru/topics/5515?page=1#20880     Поставила приоритет для %=1, для остальных *,/ = 2, +,-=3. Добавила (где 186 строка) для процента: else if (token.equals("%")) {token = tokenizer.nextToken();if (token.equals("*")) {stack.push(operand1.multiply(operand2.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(100))));} и тд. для все операторов. Работает даже со скобками :)))

Comment: Рад что у вас все получилось. Обновите, пожалуйста, ваш вопрос или добавьте свой ответ в чуть более развернутой форме, так что бы кто-нибудь с похожей проблемой мог найти ваше решение. Вдруг кому пригодится :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашла ответ (спасибо комментариям). Вот код для калькулятора с возможностью расчета процентов (input строка, например (158+15)*18% )

```
public class ReversePolishNotation {

public static final Map<String, Integer> MAIN_MATH_OPERATIONS;

static {
    MAIN_MATH_OPERATIONS = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    MAIN_MATH_OPERATIONS.put("%", 1);
    MAIN_MATH_OPERATIONS.put("*", 2);
    MAIN_MATH_OPERATIONS.put("/", 2);
    MAIN_MATH_OPERATIONS.put("+", 3);
    MAIN_MATH_OPERATIONS.put("-", 3);
}


public static String sortingStation(String expression, Map<String, Integer> operations, String leftBracket,
                                    String rightBracket) {
    if (expression == null || expression.length() == 0)
        throw new IllegalStateException("Expression isn't specified.");
    if (operations == null || operations.isEmpty())
        throw new IllegalStateException("Operations aren't specified.");

    List<String> out = new ArrayList<String>();

    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();


    expression = expression.replace(" ", "");


    Set<String> operationSymbols = new HashSet<String>(operations.keySet());
    operationSymbols.add(leftBracket);
    operationSymbols.add(rightBracket);


    int index = 0;

    boolean findNext = true;
    while (findNext) {
        int nextOperationIndex = expression.length();
        String nextOperation = "";

        for (String operation : operationSymbols) {
            int i = expression.indexOf(operation, index);
            if (i >= 0 && i < nextOperationIndex) {
                nextOperation = operation;
                nextOperationIndex = i;
            }
        }

        if (nextOperationIndex == expression.length()) {
            findNext = false;
        } else {

            if (index != nextOperationIndex) {
                out.add(expression.substring(index, nextOperationIndex));
            }

            if (nextOperation.equals(leftBracket)) {
                stack.push(nextOperation);
            }

            else if (nextOperation.equals(rightBracket)) {
                while (!stack.peek().equals(leftBracket)) {
                    out.add(stack.pop());
                    if (stack.empty()) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unmatched brackets");
                    }
                }
                stack.pop();
            }

            else {
                while (!stack.empty() && !stack.peek().equals(leftBracket) &&
                        (operations.get(nextOperation) >= operations.get(stack.peek()))) {
                    out.add(stack.pop());
                }
                stack.push(nextOperation);
            }
            index = nextOperationIndex + nextOperation.length();
        }
    }

    if (index != expression.length()) {
        out.add(expression.substring(index));
    }

    while (!stack.empty()) {
        out.add(stack.pop());
    }
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    if (!out.isEmpty())
        result.append(out.remove(0));
    while (!out.isEmpty())
        result.append(" ").append(out.remove(0));

    return result.toString();
}


public static String sortingStation(String expression, Map<String, Integer> operations) {
    return sortingStation(expression, operations, "(", ")");
}


public static BigDecimal calculateExpression(String expression) {
    String rpn = sortingStation(expression, MAIN_MATH_OPERATIONS);
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(rpn, " ");
    Stack<BigDecimal> stack = new Stack<BigDecimal>();
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        String token = tokenizer.nextToken();

        if (!MAIN_MATH_OPERATIONS.keySet().contains(token)) {
            stack.push(new BigDecimal(token));
        } else {
            BigDecimal operand2 = stack.pop();
            BigDecimal operand1 = stack.empty() ? BigDecimal.ZERO : stack.pop();
            if (token.equals("*")) {
                stack.push(operand1.multiply(operand2));
            } else if (token.equals("/")) {
                stack.push(operand1.divide(operand2));
            } else if (token.equals("+")) {
                stack.push(operand1.add(operand2));
            } else if (token.equals("-")) {
                stack.push(operand1.subtract(operand2));
            }else if (token.equals("%")) {
                token = tokenizer.nextToken();
                if (token.equals("*")) {
                    stack.push(operand1.multiply(operand2.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(100))));
                } else if (token.equals("/")) {
                    stack.push(operand1.divide(operand1.multiply(operand2.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(100)))));
                } else if (token.equals("+")) {
                    stack.push(operand1.multiply(operand2.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(100)).add(BigDecimal.valueOf(1))));
                } else if (token.equals("-")) {
                    stack.push(operand1.subtract(operand1.multiply(operand2.divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(100)))));
                }

            }
        }
    }
    if (stack.size() != 1)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expression syntax error.");
    return stack.pop();
}


private ReversePolishNotation() {
}
```

}